# For what is used ' <%#data: ... ' in embedded code blocks?

Tags: html, asp.net, gridview, codeblocks

I am trying to **insert images** in a **GridView Table**, the image is saved as **`base64`** in a **SQL DataBase**, I found in a youtube video, that you can retrieve and make the data binding with an embedded code block

**<%# ... %>**

They are using also this:

```
<DataItemTemplate>
            <asp:Image ID="Foto" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#"data:Image/png;base64," + "ImageData" %>'></asp:Image>
</DataItemTemplate>
```

For what is the **data:Image/png**, is it just format? and how is it called to search it online?

*Thanks in advance.*

*Video consulted: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sFkeJb7E_rk&t=427s (min 4:15)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data:Image/png;base64,...` is called [data URI scheme](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2397) or [RFC 2397](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2397).

There're two parts of the solution you are using:

1. The part using `<%# ... %>` is used by ASP.NET to embed C# or VB code inside your ASPX page. In your example you are promoting a string to your HTML page with the data URI printed.
2. The `data:Image/png;Base64,...` is actually used to embed a binary image inside your page. You can look at [this reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#Syntax) more details and examples (if you do not like the RFC standard document - which is sometimes harder to read).

Comment: thank you very much! that's exactly what I was searching.